# Finding equation of a path in the plane $y=z$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

What is the easiest way to see that the path $$\underline{r}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3: t \mapsto (\sin\,t,\cos\,t,\cos\,t)$$ traces out an ellipse in the plane $y=z$?

I think first rotating $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $\pi/4$ about the $x$-axis will help but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. The rotation by $\pi/4$ will yield the path $$(x',y',z')=(\sin t,\sqrt2\cos t,0)$$ in the new coordinates. How do you eliminate $t$? Use $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$:
$$x'^2+\frac{y'^2}2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your path is also contsined in $x^2+y^2=1$, which is a cylinder.
So your path is in the intersection of this cylinder and the plane $y=z$.
Geometrically, this is an ellipse, since the plane is not paralel to the axis of the cyclinder, so it cuts all generatrices.